# Could are the hypotheses inherited by $ G/N $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

A group $ G $ is said satisfy in maximal permutizer condition if $ P_{G}(M) = \langle x \in G \ \vert \ \langle x \rangle M = M \langle x \rangle \rangle = G $.
Theorem :  $ G $ is a finite group. $ G $ is supersoluble if every normal subgroup of $ G $ of with index no more than $ 2 $ satisfies the maximal permutizer condition.

For proof I suppose $ G $ is a counterexample of minimal order. Let $ N $ minimal normal subgroup of $ G $. Could are the hypotheses inherited by $ G/N $?

Comment: You haven't said what the maximal permutizer condition is. But the answer is yes. If $M/N$ is a maximal subgroup of $G/N$, then $M$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Since $ P_{G/N}(M/N) = P_{G}(M)/N = G/N $ ?

Comment: Yes that looks right!